# Why HTML comment indentation is displayed differently in browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, comments, notepad++

I was trying to beautify my html so that whenever someone click `view source` on my page can see it. So, I decided to write my name as a comment on top of my html. However, what is shown on Google Chrome's `view source` was different from what I see in Notepad++. Like in the picture :

[image]

- left = Google Chrome in view source mode.
- right = Notepad++

Why I didn't get what I typed in notepad++ ? Is it because Notepad++ use different font with Google Chrome ? If yes, what's the font used in Google Chrome ?

**How can I get what I want to display nicely on Google Chrome's view source?**

*P.S. I haven't tried it with other browsers yet.*

Comment: Probably because different editors use different fonts to show the source. Some fonts have uneven character spacing, which means you can't control the ASCII art. You also can't control line-wrapping.

Comment: I actually have seen one website that did this and they successfully wrote it nicely.

Comment: Google Chrome uses Courier New on my Ubuntu, I didn't change the default. Courier New is monospaced font so your ascii art should show properly. However maybe your font in Notepad++ isn't monspaced. You should make sure Notepad++ uses such a font.

Comment: This [website](https://layervault.com/) wrote a text. This [website](http://oak.is/) drew a face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see there is word wrap. If your line of text is too long it will be wrapped to the next line. I doubt there is a solution for this except in making the message shorter and hoping the user window is wider than the message.

Comment: The text didn't wrapped to the next line. I didn't take a screenshot of the whole thing. The texts are in the line where it supposed to be but problem is the spaces and indentations.

Comment: @ThanakronTandavas it really looks like wrapped text. In your image of chrome it is easy to recognize the "A" if you count how many lines it has, you see it has 10 where some don't add anything to the "A" (only 6 do, the others are interleaved with those). On the other hand the original only have 6 lines all used by the "A". Why would that be if it is not wrapped text? (+1 to Musa)

Comment: Oh ! I just noticed that. It actually makes sense. I will try it out this evening. I also have tried to resize window's width with other websites that successfully did this. Their texts are also get wrapped to the next line when the window is too small. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult (I would say impossible) to do this everywhere you want. I mean, the purpose of that visual appearance is to embellish your code on a platform; it differs from an editor to another whether character spacing, line wrapping or even word wrapping are used or not. Regards.

Comment: It's possible. These two websites successfully did it. This [website](https://layervault.com/) wrote a text. This [website](http://oak.is/) drew a face.